# How to implement custom user access permissions in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, permissions, cypher

Need to define access policies hierarchically in the application that uses Neo4j.

**Model**: application uses a tree structure (each `Node` has exactly one parent), which can be represented as

```
(:Node)-[:SUBTREE_OF]->(:Node)
```

for simplicity.

There are also `User`s who are members of `Group`s, which have `Permission`s. Permissions contain two properties: `objectId` that contains ID of the object for which permission is set and `accessLevel`, which can be  `WRITE`, `READ` or `NONE`.

so

```
(u:User)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group)
(g:Group)-[:WITH]->(p:Permission{objectID:"99", accessLevel:"WRITE"})
```

**Problem**: need to make possible specifying permission access level for the object that can be inherited by all its children. That means a need to determine access level of particular `User` to particular `Node` at runtime using specified permission for this object in case it is specified or the nearest specified parent permission if the permission is not specified.

How to write the query that will return `accessLevel` property of specified `Node` or the nearest parent `Node`?

Comment: The Object that a :Permission's objectID refers to...is that the same as the :Nodes in your tree structure? If the :Permission is directly targeting a node in your tree structure, and :Permissions are only part of :Groups, there's some opportunity to refactor your graph for easier queries. Also, do :Permission objects only store the objectID and accessLevel, or are there other fields?

Comment: @InverseFalcon Objects can be :Application's and :Node's. :Application's are parents for :Node's, but I decided to omit this for simplicity. :Permissions store only ObjectID and accessLevel indeed.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Is it guaranteed that if a :Node doesn't have an associated :Permission from a :Group then it's :Application will? Or are there other node types above :Application that should have a :Permission? Is there some kind of default permission that should be used if no :Permission exists for any node up the hierarchy?

Comment: :Application's will be handled by mandatory permissions specified for each :Application, so no need to make hierarchical inheritance for them and their children. :Node's will be the first objects that need inheritance for its children. Default permission should be `WRITE`, i. e. all the privileges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now your `:Permissions` are associated to `:Nodes` and `:Applications` by an objectID property, but for effective queries using graph relationships, this should probably be modeled as a relationship to the object itself. At that point it's a question of if the `accessLevel` should be stored in the `:Permission` nodes, or if you want to get rid of `:Permission` nodes entirely and model it with a `:HasPermission` relationship with an `accessLevel` property.

I'll assume that you'll want to keep your `:Permission` nodes for now.

Assuming that a `:User` can only be a member of one `:Group`, your query to get the permission for a `:Node` (or its `:Node` ancestors) becomes something like:

```
MATCH (:User{ID:123})-[:MEMBER_OF]->(group:Group), (node:Node{ID:123})
WITH group, node
// looking for a :Node going up the chain with a permission from your group
OPTIONAL MATCH (node)-[jumps:SUBTREE_OF*0..]->(target:Node)<-[:HasPermission]-(perm:Permission)<-[:WITH]-(group)
WITH node, target, perm, jumps
ORDER BY SIZE(jumps) LIMIT 1
RETURN target,  COALESCE(target = node, false) as same_node, COALESCE(perm.accessLevel, "WRITE") as accessLevel
```

The return includes the `target` :Node we eventually matched on (it will be null if we couldn't find one in the hierarchy and defaulted to the "WRITE" access level), `same_node` for whether the :Node we wanted to get permission for was the one with the permission on it (false means we found an ancestor with a permission or defaulted), and the `accessLevel` is the access level of the associated permission. You probably don't need all of these, but it's useful to have for testing that it's working properly.

EDIT

Remembered that we could easily enforce the ordering to select the nearest parent node (or the node itself) with your group permission by sorting on the number of relationships we traverse up the chain. Altered my query above to handle this.

Comment: I think that the level of access is also necessary in a separate node.

Comment: Rather than relying on implicit ordering, I edited my query to enforce the ordering so we always grab the first node up the chain that has your group permission.

Comment: @InverseFalcon The updated query is also valid for cases when :User belongs to several :Group's. That solves my problem, thank you for your time. Appreciate it. I updated the query a little bit with ID() function so it works for me: http://pastebin.com/DqBPnWH2